# Function only looping once in for loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

`getOneGoalieInformationnFromID()` is only doing a loop one time in this for loop.

```
Future<void> getGoaliesInformationFromID() {
  for (var goalieID = 0;
      goalieID < goaliesOfCurrentUserID.length;
      goalieID++) {
    getOneGoalieInformationnFromID**(goaliesOfCurrentUserID[goalieID])
        .whenComplete(() {
      getSelectedGoalieStats();
    });
  }
  super.initState();
}
```

Here is the function `getOneGoalieInformationnFromID()` only doing the loop once:

```
Future<void> getOneGoalieInformationnFromID(goalieID) async {
  try {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    await fDb
        .collection('users')
        .where('__name__', isEqualTo: goalieID)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      print(querySnapshot.docs);
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        setState(() {
          ...
```

What is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Your getOneGoalieInformationnFromID function is also a Future function you called inside the loop and that will call once

in getGoaliesInformationFromID function, instead of for-loop you should use map-loop and use for waiting function Future.wait

```
Future<void> getGoaliesInformationFromID() async{
 Future.wait( await goaliesOfCurrentUserID.map(goalieId)async{
   await getOneGoalieInformationnFromID**(goaliesOfCurrentUserID[goalieID])
      .whenComplete(() {
        getSelectedGoalieStats();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I get this error on map function.

Function expressions can't be named.  Try removing the name, or moving the function expression to a function declaration statement.

What is causing that? 

Thank you

Comment: Future<void> getGoaliesInformationFromID() async{
    Future.wait( await goaliesOfCurrentUserID.map((goalieID)async{
    await getOneGoalieInformationnFromID(goalieID);
    }));
  }

No error like this, but the function getOneGoalieInformationnFromID still only occurs one time.

Comment: Your welcome what about this getSelectedGoalieStats() if this function is also a future function you need to change this part of your code .whenComplete(() async{
        await getSelectedGoalieStats();
      });